# How to run goosh (command line google search) from WSL (Linux bash shell on Win10)?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, search

I have an installation of WSL (an ubuntu installation limited to the command line - no GUI) under Win10 home edition. I would like to perform web searches from the WSL bash command line using goosh. I might be able to use cygwin or some other shell, and also a different search engine, but I would like to use WSL/goosh (if possible) because it is/seems convenient. All the pieces are (almost) in place. I can open the *nix emulator from a windows cmd console simply by typing `bash`. It would be "nice" if I could then type a command such as `goosh my-search-string > my-text-file`.

Ultimately I just want to collect search results in a text file through command line redirection, but that is down the road. Of course I appreciate alternatives or hints on how to do this. So far I have been unable to find how to do this, and specifically whether it is at all possible to run goosh under WSL/bash.

Note some related posts but which don't answer this:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778318/use-cmd-prompt-to-search-a-word-on-google-or-other-search-engine) suggests using `start xxx` which opens a browser, defeating the purpose of working from the command line.
- [This](http://github.com/gfody/PsGoogle) might work but sends up flags as unsafe and is unsupported.

Comment: goosh seems to be based around JavaScript/CSS and likely only emulates a terminal interface. [googler](https://github.com/jarun/googler) appears perhaps closer to what you want (for `bash`). [This manpage for Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/googler.1.html) even seems to suggest it might be included with some distros (or at least available through official repositories).

Comment: @Anaksunaman thank you, that might do the job. Requires python 3.6+ though

Comment: You might try the links package with a script/alias like `links "google.com/search?q=$(echo $@ | sed 's/ /+/g')"`.

Comment: @harrymc that's a good tip. Thanks, that seems a better tool for this.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using instead of the problematic `goosh` to use the `links` package.

A script/alias such as the following can call it with a query parameter
consisting of multiple words (spaces are converted to plus):

```
links "google.com/search?q=$(echo $@ | sed 's/ /+/g')"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, as noted in the comments, [googler](https://github.com/jarun/googler) relies on Python, which is [available on Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) (outside the Microsoft Store releases). And light poking around led to the discovery that `googler` has (at least some) support on Windows itself.

This means that it is (currently) possible to run googler v4.3.2 *without* WSL/bash/Linux on Windows 10 (21H1). This was done successfully with both older copies of Python (3.7.9, 3.8.10), as well the latest Python 3.9.7 release.

*Steps:*

1. [Download and install Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).
2. Download the googler "Source code" `.zip` file (e.g. `googler-4.3.2.zip`) from the current GitHub "Releases" page for the project.  As of this writing, the latest release is [4.3.2](https://github.com/jarun/googler/releases/tag/v4.3.2) (January 2021).
3. Unzip e.g. `googler-4.3.2.zip` and run the `googler` script (no extension) via Python ex.:

   ```
    python googler search terms
   ```

If the example above doesn't work, just specify the full path to `python.exe` and/or the `googler` script. Note that you can alias this example in something like a batch file:

*ex. googler.bat*

```
"C:\path\to\python.exe" "C:\path\to\googler" %*
```

`googler` (above) is the googler script itself (not a directory). You could then place the folder containing `googler.bat` in your Windows Path environment variables (likely under your System Path) and use `googler` like so:

```
googler search terms
```

**A Minor Note On Terminals**

- Both `cmd` and PowerShell appeared to display colors, though I didn't try changing these or checking if they were correct.
- Using the [official Windows Terminal app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) had the added benefit of making the URLs returned clickable (through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>). They were opened in the default browser.